# New Broadcast receiver not being registered in Fennec

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fennec

I am trying to understand how the build system for Fennec project in Android works. As part of that, I am trying to add a new *Broadcast Receiver* to the *AndroidManifest file.*

So far I could figure out that in order to add any new Java Files to the project, we need to add them in the `MOZILLA_SOURCE_ROOT/mobile/android/base/moz.build.`

Similarly, in order to change the AndroidManifest, we have to do that in  `MOZILLA_SOURCE_ROOT/mobile/android/base/AndroidManifest.xml.in`.

Now, adding a new receiver in that doesnt work. The app doesnt just receive the broadcasts.

Please let me know, if any of findings are wrong and also the proper way to register a new Broadcast Receiver.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for some more time, finally I decided to clean build it. And it worked..!!